# Memory allocation of (key, value) pair structure, and reading from the registry

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, registry

I want to make a program, which collects some information from the Windows registry and then to save it to a file. However I´m having problems by collecting the information. I would like to store an array in a struct. My problem is specifying the size of the array after initializing the struct.

```
typedef struct RESULTSKEY{
char *ResultsKeys;
char *ResultsValues;
} RESULTSKEYS;


RESULTSKEYS RES_OS_Keys[] =
{
 { _T("ProductName"),_T(" ")},
 { _T("CSDVersion"),_T(" ") },
 { _T("BuildLab"),_T(" ") },
 { _T("SystemRoot"),_T(" ") },
};
```

Then with the following function the magic should happen.

```
for (l=0; l< _countof(RES_OS_Keys);l++)
{
    variable = (char*)ReadRegistry((LPTSTR) clave,(LPTSTR)RES_OS_Keys[l].ResultsKeys);
    RES_OS_Keys[l].ResultsValues = variable;
}
```

but of course, there is a problem: `RES_OS_Keys[l].ResultsValues` have the same values:

```
RES_OS_Keys[0] 
  { ResultsKeys=0x00420894"ProductName"  Resultsvalues=0x0012f488 "C:\WINDOWS"}

RES_OS_Keys[1] 
  { ResultsKeys=0x00420880"CSDVersion"  Resultsvalues=0x0012f488 "C:\WINDOWS"}

RES_OS_Keys[2] 
  { ResultsKeys=0x00420874"ProductName"  Resultsvalues=0x0012f488 "C:\WINDOWS"}

RES_OS_Keys[3] 
  { ResultsKeys=0x00420864"ProductName"  Resultsvalues=0x0012f488 "C:\WINDOWS"}
```

I´ve noticed, that it writes on the same memory segment. That´s why I came to the idea, that the problem is the memory allocation for the variables in the struct. I´ve been looking for methods, however I got confused. So, if some can give me an advice, I´ll be grateful.

Here is the `ReadRegistry` function:

```
unsigned char *ReadRegistry(LPTSTR clave, LPTSTR valor) 
{   
    unsigned char* buffer =new unsigned char[1024]; 
    unsigned char infoValue [1024];
    unsigned char infocadena [1024];
    HKEY hKey;
    LONG lStatus;
    DWORD dwType=REG_SZ;
    DWORD dwSize=1023;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    lStatus = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,clave,0,KEY_READ|KEY_WOW64_64KEY,&hKey);
    if (lStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
         lStatus = RegQueryValueEx(hKey,(LPCTSTR )valor, 0,&dwType, (LPBYTE)&infoValue, &dwSize);
         if (lStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS)
         {  
            for(i=0;infoValue[i]!=0 && infoValue[i]!=204;i++)
                infocadena[i]=(char)infoValue[i];

            infocadena [i]='\0';
            buffer = infocadena;
            RegCloseKey(hKey);
            return buffer;
            delete[] buffer;
         }  
    }
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    cout << "error by reading registry";
    delete[] buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be easier if you wrote it in C++, using `std::vector`s and `std::string`s.

Comment: It's hard to be sure (especially as you haven't posted the code for `ReadRegistry`) but I would say that you don't understand how to do dynamic memory allocation in C++, or even how pointers work. Probably you just need to spend some time reading a C++ book. There are lots of ways to solve this problem but the most important thing is for you to get a better understanding of the issues.

Comment: Most likely, your ReadRegistry function is reading from the registry into a static buffer and is returning the pointer to that.  Which you are saving.  But you're getting the same pointer back every time.

Comment: I edited your question, trying to make the title more meaningful, and fixing some formatting in your text.

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself a favor and:

1. Drop this obsolete error-prone hard-to-write-read-and-maintain C-style of raw string pointers, raw arrays, etc. and **use C++** (possibly with some convenient C++11 features) and **STL** containers and classes (like `std::map`, `std::wstring`, ...).
2. Drop the obsolete `TCHAR` model, and just write **Unicode** Win32 code.

The following code uses C++, STL and [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and interfaces to Win32 APIs.
Errors are represented using C++ exceptions.
Strings are stored in robust `std::wstring` class instances.
(key, value) pairs are stored in the convenient `std::map` STL container.

The code is commented, so please follow the comments inside code for further details.

For testing, I created some test data on the registry (as showed in the following screenshot):
[image: Some registry test data]

and then compiled the code from command line with VC10 (VS2010 SP1):

> ```
> C:\Temp\CppTests>cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo /MTd TestRegistry.cpp  
> TestRegistry.cpp
> ```

and ran the executable, obtaining the following output:

> ```
> C:\Temp\CppTests>TestRegistry.exe  
> BuildLab: Cool LAB  
> ProductName: My Cool Product.  
> Version: 1.2.3.4A
> ```

Compilable code follows:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Test program to read some strings from the registry.
//
// Uses C++ techniques like RAII and STL containers.
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// Build in Unicode mode 
// (it's the default inside VS IDE, since VS2005).
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

//
// Headers:
//
#include <exception>    // for std::exception
#include <iostream>     // for console output
#include <map>          // for std::map
#include <stdexcept>    // for std::runtime_error
#include <string>       // for std::wstring
#include <Windows.h>    // Win32 Platform SDK


// Link with this for registry APIs.
#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")


//
// Represents Win32 API errors.
//
class Win32Error 
    : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    // Init with message and error code
    Win32Error(const char* message, DWORD error)
        : std::runtime_error(message),
          m_error(error)
    {
    }

    DWORD ErrorCode() const
    {
        return m_error;
    }

private:
    DWORD m_error;
};

// Throws Win32Error exception based on last error code.
inline void ThrowLastWin32(const char* message)
{
    const DWORD lastError = ::GetLastError();
    throw Win32Error(message, lastError);
}


//
// RAII wrapper to Win32 registry key.
//
class RegKey
{
public:

    // Tries opening the specified key.
    // Throws a Win32Error exception on failure.
    RegKey(
        HKEY hKeyParent, 
        const std::wstring& subKey,
        REGSAM desideredAccess
        )
    {
        LONG result = ::RegOpenKeyEx(
            hKeyParent,
            subKey.c_str(),
            0,
            desideredAccess,
            &m_hKey
        );
        if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            ThrowLastWin32("Can't open registry key.");
        }
    }

    // Closes the key.
    ~RegKey()
    {
        ::RegCloseKey(m_hKey);
    }

    // Gets the wrapped key handle.
    HKEY Get() const
    {
        return m_hKey;
    }

private:
    HKEY m_hKey; // raw key resource wrapper in this RAII class
};


//
// Reads a string from the registry.
// (Throws exceptions like Win32Error on errors.)
//
std::wstring ReadRegistryString(
    HKEY hKeyParent,
    const std::wstring& keyName, 
    const std::wstring& value)
{
    // Try opening the specified key
    RegKey key( hKeyParent, keyName, KEY_READ|KEY_WOW64_64KEY);

    // First call to ::RegQueryValueEx() to get destination buffer size
    DWORD dataSize = 0;
    LONG result = ::RegQueryValueEx(
        key.Get(),      // handle to open registry key
        value.c_str(),  // the name of the registry value
        nullptr,        // reserved
        nullptr,        // no need to know the type of value
        nullptr,        // data is not required in this step
        &dataSize       // get data size, in bytes      
    );
    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        ThrowLastWin32("ReadRegistryString - Can't get buffer size.");

    // Create a string with proper size to store the value
    // read from registry.
    // Consider that sizeof(wchar_t) == 2 bytes.
    std::wstring data( dataSize/2, 'x' );

    // Second call to ::RegQueryValueEx() to get the actual string
    DWORD type;
    result = ::RegQueryValueEx(
        key.Get(),      // handle to open registry key
        value.c_str(),  // the name of the registry value
        nullptr,        // reserved
        &type,          // the type of value
        reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&data[0]), // string buffer
        &dataSize       // data size, in bytes      
    );
    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        ThrowLastWin32("ReadRegistryString - Can't get value data.");

    // Check that we are reading a string
    if (type != REG_SZ)
        throw Win32Error("ReadRegistryString - Type is not string.",
            ERROR_INVALID_DATA);

    // To avoid duouble-NUL termination,
    // remove the last NUL in the string, if present.
    // (In fact, there can be a NUL copied by ::RegQueryValueEx,
    // and there is the NUL of std::wstring).
    if (data[data.length()-1] == L'\0')
        data.resize(data.length()-1);

    return data;
}


//
// Test function: read some key/value pairs from the registry.
//
std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> ReadDesideredKeyValuePairs()
{
    // Keys to read value for    
    const wchar_t* keys[] = {
        L"ProductName",
        L"Version",
        L"BuildLab"
    };

    // Will store (key, value) pairs
    std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> result;

    // Read key/value pairs from the registry
    for (int i = 0; i < _countof(keys); i++)
    {    
        result[keys[i]] = ReadRegistryString(
                HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
                L"C64Test", 
                keys[i]
        );
    }

    return result;
}


//
// Console app entry point
//
int main()
{
    static const int kExitOk = 0;
    static const int kExitError = 1;

    try
    {
        // Call test function
        std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> result = 
            ReadDesideredKeyValuePairs(); 

        // Print result to console
        for (auto it = result.begin(); it != result.end(); ++it)
            std::wcout << it->first << ": " << it->second << std::endl;

        // All right
        return kExitOk;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        // Print error message
        std::wcerr << "\n*** ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl;

        // Exit with failure code
        return kExitError;
    }    
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ResultsValues` variable is a pointer, so you will need to allocate memory for it before you can store the result of 'ReadRegistry' into it.

In case 'ReadRegistry' is a function you have written, what is the type of the return value? If it is a pointer, you may also have memory allocation issues in the function, you may want to either use a CString as the return value or take the result-pointer as a parameter.

NOTE: you will also need to free the allocated memory afterwards!

**EDIT**: comment to the edited question:

a) make the function `void ReadRegistry(LPTSTR clave, LPTSTR valor, LPTSTR infocadena)`

b) delete declaration of variables `infocadena` and `buffer` and all references of `buffer`in the function

c) allocate memory for `RES_OS_Keys[l].ResultsValues` in the calling logic and then call the function like `ReadRegistry((LPTSTR) clave,(LPTSTR)RES_OS_Keys[l].ResultsKeys, RES_OS_Keys[l].ResultsValues);`

d) free the allocated memory afterwards