# How can I preallocate and initialize the character sequence inside `std::basic_string`?

Tags: c++, stdstring, unique-ptr

I am wondering how I could preallocate and initialize the character sequence inside an ordinary C++ string. The occasion for the question is querying the Windows registry for values. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16304707/1794538) for some example code. The trouble is that the system call writes into an array allocated by the caller. I've already solved the immediate problem with an allocated buffer, but this solution has what seems to be an extraneous string copy. This got me curious about the general question, one more geared at library authors, about how one could eliminate the extra operation.

The [constructors for `std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) don't include an obvious way of doing this. In many ways I'd like to have a string constructor with a `std::unique_ptr` argument that absorbs the allocation behind the pointer as its internal storage. I'm thinking of something like this sample code:

```
size_t len;
// ... Determine len
std::string::allocator_type a = std::string::allocator_type();
std::unique_ptr< char_t[] > p( a.allocate( len ) );
// ... Copy characters to p
std::string s( p, len, a );  // constant-time constructor
```

This doesn't work because there's no such constructor. The question is about how one might implement such a constructor.

It seems that the right way is to define a custom allocator whose `allocate` function returns the pre-allocated storage and does so only once. Presumably this class would itself be generic, instantiated with the string allocator (like in the example). This seems like it would work, but I'm sure I don't understand all the ramifications of that approach.

Comment: Where exactly is the extraneous string copy?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not letting `std::string` do the copy? As it is now `p` has single ownership but you're _sharing_ it with `s`. You need to do `p.release()` when you pass it to std::string.

Comment: @DavidBrown Where you allocate a `char buf[SOMELENGTH];`, then you `GetSomeRegistryValue(buf, "key");` into the buffer, then you construct an `std::string str(buf);` - then the constructor will copy the contents of the buffer. But this smells like **premature optimization** and anyway, doing this is pretty idiomatic when wrapping a C library in C++.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's an optimization, sure. It's not premature, though, since I've already moved on for practical code. I was really wondering whether the std::basic_string classes countenance this style of initialization. Note the phrase "geared at library authors".

Comment: @CaptainObvlious What you describe is roughly what I'm already doing. The question is how to avoid the second copy, the one _after_ the system call does the first.